# Find the recurrence solution of this relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How would we find the solution of the recurrence relation: $a_n = 2a_{n−1} + 3 · 2^n$ ?

After trying it, I've found it to be $a_n = 2^{n-1} (c_1 + 6n)$

Not sure if this is right..

Thanks!

Comment: We are here to help *you* find answers. So, what have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: The above and also: what do you call "solution" to in this case? A formula only involving $\,n\,$ or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very simple technique is available, since this is a first-order recurrence. Unwind it:

$$\begin{align*}
a_n&=2a_{n-1}+3\cdot2^n\\
&=2(2a_{n-2}+3\cdot2^{n-1})+3\cdot2^n\\
&=2^2a_{n-2}+2\cdot3\cdot2^n\\
&=2^2(2a_{n-3}+3\cdot2^{n-2})+2\cdot3\cdot2^n\\
&=2^3a_{n-3}+3\cdot3\cdot2^n\\
&\;\vdots\\
&=2^ka_{n-k}+k(3\cdot2^n)&&\text{conjecture}\\
&\;\vdots\\
&=2^na_0+n(3\cdot2^n)\\
&=(a_0+3n)2^n
\end{align*}$$

Now prove by induction that $a_n=(a_0+3n)2^n$ really is a solution to the recurrence: if $a_n=(a_0+3n)2^n$, then

$$\begin{align*}
a_{n+1}&=2a_n+3\cdot2^{n+1}\\
&=2(a_0+3n)2^n+3\cdot2^{n+1}\\
&=(a_0+3n+3)2^{n+1}\\
&=\big(a_0+3(n+1)\big)2^{n+1}\;,
\end{align*}$$

exactly as desired.

Comment: But this differs from what wolfram says?

Comment: @jtm22: What does Wolfram|Alpha give you?

Comment: @BrianMScott - wolfram verifys that the solution is $a_n = 2^{n-1} (c_1 + 6n)$

Comment: @jtm22: That really doesn’t help much, since you haven’t said what $c_1$ is.

Comment: @BrianMScott I was thinking that $c_1$ is similar to what GlenO was saying?  Do you suggest I just disregard their reasoning - http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%5Bn%5D%3D2*a%5Bn-1%5D%2B3*2%5En ?  Thanks

Comment: @jtm22: Since you didn’t specify any initial value, I suspect that $c_1$ there is an arbitrary constant that depends on the the initial value. Note that if you set $c_1=2a_0$, the W|A closed form reduces to mine.

Comment: Makes sense Brian, Thanks!

Comment: @jtm22: You’re welcome!

Comment: @BrianMScott Are you missing a 3 in this solution?

Comment: @jtm22: Yes, there was a typo in the very last line, which I’ve now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What happens when you try a solution of the form
$$
a_n = b_n + c\cdot2^n
$$
and what value of $c$ simplifies the recurrence relation?

Comment: I've found the solution to be $a_n = 2^{n-1} (c_1 + 6n)$